# Forge Authentication: How to handle GatewayTimeout on Refresh

Tags: autodesk-forge

We've got an Autodesk Forge application that uses an initial 3-legged OAuth to get a token, and then keeps refreshing it as needed to get things done.

We're running into occasions where we get back a GATEWAY TIMEOUT error from the RefreshToken call.
We do retry up to 3 times after encountering it - but it seems like we immediately get BAD REQUESTs.

We feel like the Refresh is actually happening (so a new refresh token is generated) - but because of the Gateway Timeout, we're not getting the new refresh token back.

I feel like the Gateway timeout is being reported in Autodesk's API wrapper service (Apogee?) - so there's nothing I can control about it - is that correct?  Any recommendations for what to do?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: When did this happen? Yesterday, our identity service has a planned maintenance around 10 o'clock at the PST timezone. We apologize for any inconvenience had caused.

Comment: @EasonKang it was on 1/8 at 23:32 - not sure of the time zone. Europe? Think it has happened before

Comment: If my calculation is correct, Jun 18 10:00 am PST is around 19:00am CET(Central European Time). Has it happened again? For better discussion, could you consult us via  forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com